# Mdi child window merged with menubar on maximize

Tags: c#, winforms

MDI child window control box(highlighted in red) gets merged with menu bar on maximize as shown below.

[image]

I want the control box(highlighted in red) at as shown in below image.

[image]

I tried to do it using Dock property but then I was not able to resize it.

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

What will you do with the form that goes through the UserControl.

I have a similar interface in my software and development UserControl with Dock = Fill in the panel where you want to place the Form.

Another way is think to implements:

```
private void FrmChild_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //TODO SET POSITION OF FORM INTO BLU AREA
}
```

Reimplementing this method you can manage the placement of the form to your liking

Comment: But after setting fill propety, I am not able to resize the UserControl.

Comment: You want that the form can be resized only in the blue areas? @SagarGupta

Comment: Yes, form should be resized in skyblue area.

Comment: At this point you should manage by code the MDIForm_Move/FrmChild_Resize event. @SagarGupta